# How to compute$\lfloor k^{\frac{m}{n}}\rfloor$?

Tags: computational-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given accurate floating point arithmetic, how to calculate 
$$a=\lfloor k^{\frac{m}{n}}\rfloor$$

in an efficient way? Here $k,m,n$ are positive integers and $\frac{m}{n}$ and $k^{\frac{m}{n}}$ are floating point numbers.

The problem is that rounding errors may cause an error in a. The only idea coming to my mind is to calculate $a$ in the obvious way and check if 
$a^\frac{n}{m}\leq k < (a+1)^\frac{n}{m}$.

Comment: My educated guess would be to calculate $x = k^m$ first, without any numerical rounding errors, since they are integers. Then calculate $y = x^{1 / n}$ by means of the usual "pow" function or $y = e^{1/n\log(x)}$, whichever you believe it has more accuracy in your machine. Then just apply the integer part. Is that what you were looking for or did I totally misunderstand your question?

Comment: @7raiden7: This will work when $k^m$ is small enough.

Comment: Do you have an example of a triple $(k, m, n) $ that gives you inaccurate results?

Comment: @7raiden7: what I ment was that your method generally  needs big integer calculations. I prefer singles for the speed.

Comment: Let's assume `gcd(m, n) = 1` to begin with. If not, factor out `gcd(m, n)`. You have an integer `(k)` with a positive rational exponent, `(m/n)`. If `(m)` is significantly large, you need a bignum library (e.g., [gmp](https://gmplib.org/)) to calculate $k^{m}$, and the `mpz_root` function to find its n-th root - which will return an integer (`mpz_t`) value, and has therefore already 'applied' the `floor` function.